# If a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is periodic with any $P\in\mathbb{R}$, is it necessarily constant?

Tags: real-analysis, periodic-functions

Suppose I've been given a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with the property that for all $x,P\in\mathbb{R}$, $f(x+P)=f(x)$. Does it follow that $f$ is a constant function?

I've been trying to come up with a counterexample to this claim for a few minutes, but have had no success. Intuitively, it seems like the answer should be yes because fixing an arbitrary $x$ and letting $P$ vary in $\mathbb{R}$ should make the quantity $x+P$ sweep through all possible real numbers, so then the statement $f(x+P)=f(x)$ would boil down to $f(x_0)=f(x)$ (here, $x_0$ is any real number), which I think is only satisfied when $f$ is constant.

I'd appreciate a rigorous proof of the truth or falsity of this claim.

Comment: Consider arbitrary $x,y$ and let $P=y-x$. Then by your assumptions $f(x+P)=f(y)=f(x)$, so $f$ is constant as $x,y$ were arbitrary.

Comment: Your argument is a perfectly rigorous proof.

Comment: @EthanBolker somehow, I feel like it isn't. I guess I got some reading to do :P

Comment: @A.E.Rosas What I think you should learn from this is that a clear sentence in English can count as rigorous mathematics. It's often better than the equivalent content expressed with formulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(y)=f(x+(y-x))=f(x)$$
So with $P=y-x$ we obtain thę thesis.

Comment: Justifying writing $P=y-x$ will be a question for some other time. For now, this is convincing. Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is constant.
$$f(x)=f(0+x)=f(0)$$
for any $x\in\mathbb R$, using $P=x$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If $P=x$, shouldn't $f(x+P)=f(2x)$? Also, why does the value of $f$ at $0$ matter?

Comment: I’m using the periodicity for $f(0+x)=f(0)$. $f(0)$ is a constant but there’s nothing special about $0$.

Comment: After reflecting on your response a bit more, it makes much more sense now. Thank you so much!